# Get byte array from openssl_encrypt PHP 7.0

Tags: php, cryptography, aes

I use following C# Code to encrypt a Byte Array:

```
public static byte[] AES256_Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key)
    {
        var aesAlg = new AesManaged
        {
            KeySize = 256,
            Key = key,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
            IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
```

Input Bytes: 8F 21 FF 43 49 27

Private key: C8 AE 1D EC D8 25 8D 52 6F 56 FB 13 F1 5D 3C 84 E0 02 16 89 34 8F 32 87 10 0A B6 CD 81 27 DE 7E

Output: F1 00 ED B4 25 8F A6 D5 13 32 4A 8E DE 87 0C 3F

Now I want to calculate the same in PHP:

```
$plaintext = chr(0x8F). chr(0x21). chr(0xFF). chr(0x43). chr(0x49). chr(0x27);

$method = 'aes-256-ecb';

$key = chr(0xc8). chr(0xae ). chr(0x1d ). chr(0xec ). chr(0xd8 ). chr(0x25 ). chr(0x8d ). chr(0x52 ). chr(0x6f ). chr(0x56 ). chr(0xfb ). chr(0x13 ). chr(0xf1 ). chr(0x5d ). chr(0x3c ). chr(0x84
). chr(0xe0 ). chr(0x02 ). chr(0x16 ). chr(0x89 ). chr(0x34 ). chr(0x8f ). chr(0x32 ). chr(0x87 ). chr(0x10 ). chr(0x0a ). chr(0xb6 ). chr(0xcd ). chr(0x81 ). chr(0x27 ). chr(0xde ). chr(0x7e);

$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
```

Output will be: y2ipJIV4m96LKDu7jI+Mrg== (which is not my Hex Value when I convert it from ASCII to Hex)

What do I need to get a byte array back?

Comment: Padding is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. How can I solve it?

Comment: Preferably you don't. ECB is insecure and padding mode with zeros is not deterministic for all messages (particularly you cannot send messages that end with zeros). Using `PaddingMode.PKCS7` should do it - but as it is the default you don't have to explicitly specify it, you could just remove the line.

Comment: Ok and the PHP Script Mode is PKCS7 too?

Comment: Yep, OpenSSL default.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes tried, the PHP output is still the same of course, my c# output is: `CB 68 A9 24 85 78 9B DE 8B 28 3B BB 8C 8F 8C AE` which not match with the php output

Comment: I tried 0 instead of  `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` but still not the same result as c#

Comment: You've either got to change the padding in the C# code or the PHP code. You probably need to explicitly use `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` as option. Beware that there are two ways of zero pad, one pads always, the other one only pads when necessary. So check your result with e.g. a 16 byte input plaintext.